# Wordpress - display posts from a specific custom taxonomy and a certain tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need a `tax_query` that assigned to specific custom category and tags.
Below query showing all products  but I need the products to a particular category.

Here `tag="sale"`, `category="look"`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'look' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'sale',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: It looks like you *have* a tax query. What is the problem? If you can be more specific you will probably get better help.

Comment: i want that from "look" category those product assign to "sale" tag, i want to display  and above query show all product assign to "sale" tag

Comment: Without testing, the above query looks like it should show all products with "look" product category *and* "sale" product tag.

Comment: But it is not happening it shows all products assign to sale tag

Comment: sorry,it is showing right thing,there is a product in second page with a sale tag.extremely sorry brother,plz don't mond

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this

```
$new = new WP_Query('category_name=look&tag=sale');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => array('videos','image','audio'),
        'category_name' => 'look',
        'tag'=>'sale'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```